# Add objects to panel, without starting over?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, panel

Assume I already have created a Frame and Panel.  I am doing some calculations and I want to add something to the existing graphics that are already displayed in that Frame / Panel.  *How can I add to that existing Graphics object?*

For example, starting with the code below, this creates a simple window with some graphics.  Now that it is up on the screen, and the "paintComponent" method has been executed, I want to add additional graphics to this object (lines, boxes, ...)

I see only two options:

1. Create a brand new object and start from "scratch" adding all the old objects to the Graphics object "g"
2. Put logic into the "paintComponent" method to listen for additional objects to be added and then wait for the frame to be repainted (e.g. frame.repaint() )

Neither seems particularly elegant.  What is the "standard" solution?  What is the right OO way to think about this situation?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 

public class testSimpleOverlay extends JPanel
{
    public testSimpleOverlay()                       // set up graphics window
    {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  // draw graphics in the panel
    {
        int width = getWidth();             // width of window in pixels
        int height = getHeight();           // height of window in pixels

        super.paintComponent(g);            // call superclass to make panel display correctly


        g.drawString("Hello, World", 100, 150); 
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 40); 
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 100); 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testSimpleOverlay panel = new testSimpleOverlay();                            // window for drawing
        JFrame application = new JFrame();                            // the program itself

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   // set frame to exit
                                                                  // when it is closed
        application.add(panel);           

        application.setSize(500, 400);         // window is 500 pixels wide, 400 high
        application.setVisible(true);          
    }

}
```

For those interested in more detail, I intend to put a rasterized image (not a PNG or JPEG, but a computation) on the screen and then highlight portions of the image as my code "finds" objects in the image.

One reason I am not thrilled about Option (1) is that eventually, I will have a long list of objects in the Panel.  It implies that I will need to wait for the entire computation to complete to get all the "highlights".

I'd like to see the highlights as they appear on the screen.  That means I either need to wait for the entire computation to finish (as above) or I need to re-render from the start of the list of highlights after each new highlight is added.  Each rendering will take longer and longer when all I really want to do is add to the existing rendering.

Neither of these options seems very clever.  There must be a better way...

Comment: Render to an offscreen buffer, update that buffer as the computation proceeds and request a repaint, and blit the buffer to the screen on repaint.

Comment: My understanding of the Graphics2D architecture is that every g.object adds something to a list of objects to render.  Are you suggesting that I render in my offscreen buffer, but still start from scratch with a clean panel each time?  That's what I'm trying to avoid.  Can I copy the onscreen buffer to an offscreen buffer and add to that?

Comment: If it comes to increasing computation speed, look into the fork/join framework. It splits computation so multiple threads can work on one goal. I'm not really sure what you mean by "seeing all highlights as they appear on screen". If highlighting, you mean as in "hover over something and it lights up", but wanting to see the highlights right away, that depends on how you plan on highlighting things

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that the offscreen buffer contains the current state of the computation, and that you just update it with the latest changes as the computation finds them.

Comment: blit + java in Google gives relatively bad hits... can you provide a reference for "BLIT"?

Comment: Sorry, I just mean `g.drawImage`. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Something else useful to Google would be "Double Buffering", which is a technique to avoid flickering in animation, but is essentially also what you want for this kind of progressive display.

Answer (score 1):

> "What is the right OO way to think about this situation?"

1. Use an `interface`, say a `Drawable` with a method `draw` to override

   ```
   public interface Drawable {
       public void draw(Graphics);
   }
   ```
2. Have one or more class implement that class

   ```
   public class Ball implements Drawable {
       ...
       @Override
       public void draw(Graphics g) {
           g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Keep a `List<Drawable>` in the panel class. Iterate through the List in the paint method and call each one's draw method

   ```
   List<Drawable> drawables;
   ...
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       if (drawables != null) {
           for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
               drawable.draw(g);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Whenever you want to add another drawable object, just add it to the list and repaint

   ```
   public void addDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
       drawables.add(drawable);
       repaint();
   }
   ```
5. Keep in mind, you can implement `Drawable` with as many different kind of classes you want. You can have a `Square`, `Circle`, `Sheep`, `Dragon`, as long as they implement the interface and override the `draw` method, it can be added to the list and be drawn in the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: Nice... this is the philosophy I was seeking to understand.  Now to put it to practice and see if I can make it work!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BufferedImage` and use it as an off-screen buffer, progressively render your results to that buffer, and then draw it to the screen when your component gets painted.

Something like this:

```
public class Overlay extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage buffer;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (buffer == null) {
            buffer = (BufferedImage) createImage(
                             getSize().width, getSize().height);
        }
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public BufferedImage getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
public class Calculate implements Runnable {
    private Overlay overlay;

    public void run() {
        // perform calculations
        Graphics2D g2 = overlay.getBuffer().createGraphics();
        // update buffer
        g2.dispose();
        overlay.repaint();
    }
}

new Thread(new Calculate(overlay).start();
```

I haven't done this for a while. I can't remember if you want to keep the graphics object around the whole time, while the calculations are proceeding, or if you want to dispose of it and create a new one for each update. Also, if the component can be resized, or if the image doesn't fill the entire component, there are other considerations about recreating the buffer at a different size, and painting the entire component.

See this [off-screen paint example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/OffScreenPaintcreateGraphicsfromBufferedImage.htm) for more details.

Comment: Close...let me explain further:  Step 1:  create a background object.  This object contains features in it.  Create a graphics object that contains many shapes (e.g. rectangles) that represent these features.  Show this to the user so they don't have to wait forever to see what I'm working on.  Step 2:  begin sifting through the objects that have been displayed on the screen.  When you find one that matches what you want, draw a circle around it.  This step could take a long time, so you don't want the user to wait to re-render the whole thing and you want to show incremental progress

Comment: Okay. Once you have an off-screen buffer, it is easy to e.g., paint a background image to it, draw rectangles on it, draw circles on it, etc. There would be "re-rendering the whole thing". When you have figured out where to draw a circle, you just draw the circle, and call repaint.